# InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I have two VPCs. One is blue vpc (vpc_id = vpc-0067ff2ab41cc8a3e), another is shared VPC (vpc_id = vpc-076a4c26ec2217f9d). VPC peering connects these two VPCs. I provision MariaDB in the shared VPC. But, I got errors below.

Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-076a4c26ec2217f9d and the EC2 security group is in vpc-0067ff2ab41cc8a3e
status code: 400, request id: 75954d06-375c-4680-b8fe-df9a67f2574d

Below is the code. Can someone help?

```
module "master" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "2.20.0"
  identifier = var.master_identifier
  engine            = var.engine
  engine_version    = var.engine_version
  instance_class    = var.instance_class
  allocated_storage = var.allocated_storage
  storage_type      = var.storage_type
  storage_encrypted = var.storage_encrypted
  name     = var.mariadb_name
  username = var.mariadb_username
  password = var.mariadb_password
  port     = var.mariadb_port
  vpc_security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-shared.outputs.default_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-blue.outputs.default_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.worker_group_general_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.worker_group_gitea_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.all_workers_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.cluster_security_group_id]
  maintenance_window = var.maintenance_window_master
  backup_window      = var.backup_window_master
  multi_az = true
  tags = {
    Owner       = "MariaDB"
    Environment = "blue-green"
  }
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["audit", "general"]
  subnet_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-shared.outputs.database_subnets
  create_db_option_group = true
  apply_immediately = true
  family = var.family
  major_engine_version = var.major_engine_version
  final_snapshot_identifier = var.final_snapshot_identifier
  deletion_protection = false
  parameters = [
    {
      name  = "character_set_client"
      value = "utf8"
    },
    {
      name  = "character_set_server"
      value = "utf8"
    }
  ]
  options = [
    {
      option_name = "MARIADB_AUDIT_PLUGIN"
      option_settings = [
        {
          name  = "SERVER_AUDIT_EVENTS"
          value = "CONNECT"
        },
        {
          name  = "SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS"
          value = "7"
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}

module "replica" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "2.20.0"
  identifier = var.replica_identifier
  replicate_source_db = module.master.this_db_instance_id
  engine            = var.engine
  engine_version    = var.engine_version
  instance_class    = var.instance_class
  allocated_storage = var.allocated_storage
  username = ""
  password = ""
  port     = var.mariadb_port
  vpc_security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-shared.outputs.default_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-blue.outputs.default_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.worker_group_general_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.worker_group_gitea_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.all_workers_security_group_id,
                            data.terraform_remote_state.eks-blue.outputs.cluster_security_group_id]

  maintenance_window = var.maintenance_window_replica
  backup_window      = var.backup_window_replica
  multi_az = false
  backup_retention_period = 0
  create_db_subnet_group = false
  create_db_option_group    = false
  create_db_parameter_group = false
  major_engine_version = var.major_engine_version
}
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Some of security groups are not from the VPC where the rds is located at. So remove the foreign SGs from `vpc_security_group_ids`.

Comment: I have EKS deployed at blue VPC. I provision MariaDB at shared VPC. VPC peering connects these two VPCs. The EKS needs to access MariaDB at shared VPC. I provisioned redis and elasticsearch in the same way. It has no problem. But, it is not the case of MariaDB.

Comment: In another word, I would like to access the MariaDB which provisioned in Shared VPC from blue VPC. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, what you should do is to have `vpc_security_group_ids` from the VPC where your RDS is. In your case it would be **shared vpc**:

```
vpc_security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.vpc-shared.outputs.default_security_group_id]
```

Having this one SG, you would add **rules** to it to allow ingress traffic from other security groups. So basically, your RDS would have **one SG with multiple ingress rules**. The ingress rules would specify other security groups as allowed.